# how to remove shadow from the foreground using opencv 2.1.0 version

Tags: opencv

I have been testing two different implementation of Mixture of Gaussians (MOG) for background subtraction. One is using opncv2.1.0, cvCreateGaussianBGModel + cvUpdateBGStatModel and another is using opencv 2.4.3, BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 class.

```
Now, 2.4.3 provide a parameter called bShadowDetect, to identify the shadow area by gray   color. But my experience with this implementation is, it does not provide the accuracy of   shadow detection. It varies according to the parameter fTau. The other issue with this   implementation is performance hit. For 640 X 480 resolution video, it is generating below 5   fps, By switching to release mode of project I get improvement upto 7 to 8 FPS.  

The another implementation of MOG is using 2.1.0. I have configured GaussianBG state   Model 's paramenters and then I am calling cvUpdateBGStatModel each time I receive a new   frame.  

For performance improvement, I have converted my frames to gray frames before I send it   for state update. My best performance till now is using opencv 2.1.0 and which is around 30   FPS for 640 X 480 resolution frames. So, currently I am preferring opencv 2.1.0 version's   MOG for background subtraction. But Here I come to face the issue of shadow removal. Here,   I want to detect only moving object. that is without shadow, and draw a rectangle to   highlight.   

Any help in this context will be grateful.
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The code that i had implemented in my project for background subtraction was of my own.I didnt use these inbuilt functions as many of them were very slow.

What i did was:-

1. consider a pixel , if its value didnt change for a maybe around 15-20 frames or so, then that pixel corresponds to the pixel of background. and we save that pixel in a image. and we iterate this process over 10000 frames to cover the complete image.(using we got the approximate image of the background without foreground objects)
2. To remove background what i did was, i took each and every pixel compared its R,G,B values with the pixel corresponding to the background image.(take a mean sqare of the difference between R,G,B values of the pixels) If this value is less than a threshold value(which should be set by you maybe using a slider bar) , then that pixel correspond to background  and then what i did was i took another image and made that correponding pixel black, else that pixel correspond to the foreground object and copy its RGB values into our new image. This process is iterated over all the pixels. (in this manner u can remove the background from the foreground)
3. To detect shadow what u can do is change the threshold value according to your need using the slider bar.

Comment: Thanks Sumit for response. Is it possible for you to provide any video url of what you have implemented ?

Comment: @Sam i haven't uploaded the work that i had done.

Now where r u facing problem, have u understood what i have written... then it should be easy to implement in the code.

Comment: Sumit, What I have implemented is I mentioned above. And I think that implementation is covering the first two steps you have mentioned. All I need to take care of your third step. Using MOG implementation using opencv 2.1.0 is giving me acceptable performance. Tell me the FPS vs Resolution statistics of your implementation. I can obtain upto 30 fps for 640 X 480 resolution.

Comment: why do u need more than 30fps for your project...30fps is very good so that means MOG implementation is very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative OpenCV based implementation of many recent shadow detection algorithms, providing much higher quality of shadow detection:

http://arma.sourceforge.net/shadows/

There is also an associated [journal article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.1233.pdf), describing all the implemented algorithms and their various trade-offs (eg. quality vs speed).